# 1С проблема со сборкой xml

Tags: android, 1с

Доброго  времени суток. Я хочу собрать андроид приложение с 1С. Я установил и прописал пути для всех компонентов. В `java` есть `java.exe` и `jar.exe`, а в `apache ant` есть `bat` файл, `sdk` тоже установлен.

```
JDK:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

Android:C:\android-sdk

Apache ant:C:\1cmobile\apache-ant-1.10.0
```

В итоге, выдает вот такую ошибку:

> `{ManagedApplicationModule(16,3)}`: Процедура или функция с указанным
>   именем не определена `(OpenHelp)      <<?>>OpenHelp("Configuration")`;
>   Мобильное приложение содержит синтаксические ошибки.